# ¿Cómo activar un botón al llenar dos textbox en un webform? ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp

necesito que un botón este desactivado hasta que se completen los campos de dos TextBox.

Uso webform con c# en asp .net, tengo un formulario para el cambio de contraseña, y hasta que se llenen los campos con sus validaciones ya hechas se debe activar el botón.
Cuando los dos textbox se llenen se habilita el botón, el cual muestra un modal con un mensaje de que el nip se actualizó y debe cerrar sesión.

Tengo el siguiente código

```
<div id="cp"> 
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-10">
<asp:Label ID="lnnip" runat="server" Text="INGRESE UN NUEVO NIP DE 4 NUMEROS"></asp:Label>
<asp:textbox TextMode = "Password" id="clave1" maxlength="4"  
minlength="4" placeholder="NUEVO NIP" runat="server" autocomplete="off"  
TextChanged="clave1_TextChanged"></asp:textbox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" for="n1" id="n1"   
controltovalidate="clave1" errormessage="Este campo no puede quedar 
vacío"/>
</div>
</div>

<!--CONFIRMAR NIP-->    
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-10">
<asp:textbox TextMode = "Password" id="clave2" maxlength="4" minlength="4" placeholder="CONFIRMAR NIP" runat="server" autocomplete="off"> 
</asp:textbox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" for="n2" id="n2" 
controltovalidate="clave2" errormessage="Este campo no puede quedar  
vacío" />
</div>
</div>

<!--CONFIRMAR-->       
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<asp:Button runat="server" name="Mnip" id="Mnip" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nnm" class="btn btn-primary nav-link" text="CONFIRMAR">  
</asp:Button>

<!--COMPARAR NIPS-->    
<asp:CompareValidator id= "CompareValidator1" runat = "server" 
 ControlToCompare = "clave1" ControlToValidate = "clave2" ErrorMessage = 
"LOS NIP NO SON IGUALES"></asp:CompareValidator> 
 </div>
 </div>

 <!--VENTANA MODAL-->
<div class="modal fade" id="nnm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="nnmlLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-body">
       <h1>NIP GUARDADO CON EXITO
        <asp:Button name="ConfNIP" id="ConfNIP" runat="server" text="ACEPTAR" OnClick="ConfNIP_Click" class="btn btn-primary"/></h1>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
    </div>
   <!-- VENTANA MODAL-->

    </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

Gracias saludos

Comment: escribir en mayusculas en internet se considera gritar y no esta bien viste. de paso mira [ask].

Comment: Y si en código, no en la pantalla de definición de la interfaz gráfica, definieras un StartTimer que cada cierto tiempo comprobara la longitud del texto introducido, y si esta es mayor que 0 en ambos, lo habilitaras? Se que seria una solución algo chapuza, pero podría funcionar

Comment: Puedes usar jQuery y agregar una función que se ejecute al cambiar el valor de los textbox, después utiliza CSS para habilitar el botón.

Comment: @henocsalinas como podria hacer eso?

Comment: Aun mas sencillo que el jquery podria ser que a los dos text box les asocies un par de **RequiredFieldValidator**, estos impedirian que se ejecute el codigo del boton y de paso le dan al usuario un indicativo de que los dos text box son obligatorios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar jQuery y agregar una función que se ejecute al cambiar el valor de los textbox, después utiliza CSS para habilitar el botón.

agrega este codigo a los javascripts de tu pagina:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            function checkFields() {                    
                $(".senderButton").prop( "disabled", !($(".checkfield1").val() != "" && $(".checkfield2").val() != ""));                    
            }

            checkFields();
            $(".checkfield1").change(checkFields);
            $(".checkfield2").change(checkFields);
        });

    </script>
```

al un campo agregale la propiedad **CssClass="checkfield1"**
al otro agregale la propiedad  **CssClass="checkfield2"**

al boton colocale  **CssClass="senderButton"**

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, lo he probado y no me funciona, nose que he hecho nada :c